# RealmJS:How to write sorted fetch query where inner object is Key-Value?

Tags: react-native, realm

Product has many details like: productName, manufactured date,  manufacturer name, product type etc. But I need to support flexibility of having no defined schema for product details. To achieve this below is the Realm-JS schema.

```
import Realm from 'realm';
export default class ProductModel extends Realm.Object { }
    ProductModel.schema = {
        name: 'ProductModel',
        properties: {
            productAttributes: { type: 'list', objectType: 'ProductDetailsModel' },
            ID: { type: 'string', optional: true },        
        }
    };
```

---

```
import Realm from 'realm';
export default class ProductDetailsModel extends Realm.Object { }
ProductDetailsModel.schema = {
    name: 'ProductDetailsModel',
    properties: {
        attributeName: { type: 'string', optional: true },
        attributeValue: { type: 'string', optional: true },
    }
};
```

This flexibility is yielding in complexity of writing sort query. I need to be able to sort based on Product Attribute values. Let us say 'Product Name' is on attribute of Product, I need to fetch Product sorted by 'Product Name' in 'A-Z' or reverse order.

```
var productList = realm.objects('ProductModel').sorted(<Some query string>)
```

Please help me to **write query to fetch the ProductModel from DB based on some values(productName or manufacturer name etc..) sorted order?**

P.S. Other option which I am aware is get the realm objects and sort using Array.sort.

Update 1:
When I try to do sort with below query:

```
    let item = this.realm.objects('ProductModel').filtered("productAttributes.attributeName = " + "\"" + "serialNo" + "\"")
    .sorted('productAttributes.attributeValue', false);
```

I am getting below error

> Cannot sort on key path 'productAttributes.attributeValue': property 'ProductModel.productAttributes' is of unsupported type 'array'.